# Can't see new ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I recently set up an old desktop with ubuntu sever 12.04 32 bit. After finishing the installation and logging into the server, I tried to access it from other computers (both windows and ubuntu) on the network, but I couldn't see it anywhere.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

> **Important:** as [hudolejev suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/245834/4629), seeing is different from logging in.
> If you can ping the server but not `ssh` into it, then make sure you
> have installed the SSH server (run `sudo apt-get install ssh`) and start it:
>
> ```
> sudo service ssh start
> ```
>
> If you *can't* ping the server, follow the steps below to diagnose the problem:

---

You have to *move along!* First of all, check it's connected to the network.

Run `ifconfig` to check that a network card is detected and configured correctly.
You should see an `ethX` card with an IP and **`UP`**, something like that:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:1a:bd:b6:3c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:36ff:febd:b64b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:380931 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:488362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:53036441 (53.0 MB)  TX bytes:522204820 (522.2 MB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:da000000-da020000
```

Try to `ping` that IP from the other computers and your server itself.
Then, try to `ping` the router (run `route -n` to see its address).

Also check that you don't have the IPTables firewall activated by running:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Use `tcpdump` or [Wireshark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wireshark/) to see if the traffic really reaches the server.
When really desperate, `cat /var/log/{syslog,dmesg,kern.log} | tail -n 200` and
look for some handy message from the kernel.

If it still doesn't work, then repeat this procedure with the other
computers. That seems more like a general *network administration*
problem, rather than Ubuntu's; you can get better help on that
subject at SuperUser.

Comment: Part of what we do on AU is solve Layer 8 problems. It's not nice to tell OP it's their fault.

Comment: But IMHO if Ubuntu is configured correctly (it probably is, if he just did a fresh install and these steps succeded) then it's better to take this to a specialized site, like SuperUser (where it'll get more attention). Editing to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to access it

How? SSH? Telnet? HTTP?

Is SSH daemon running on server?

```
ps ax | grep sshd
```

If not, `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting. I had this exact same issue. It seems app armor gets hung up on if you make a change to the eth0, it really wants to block the static IP as its looking for it to be DHCP. Just make sure you double check the config in /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux machine check `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. If you have in your shares option `browseable = no`, this means that you can mount the share but you can't see it on your network ,it's like invisible share. You'll need to edit these.

Restart Samba for it to take effect:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```